# как сохранить правильный порядок строк pandas

Tags: python, pandas, order, merge

Код:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'Name' : ['LingS', 'DoammB', 'VoammE', 'CommI'], 
                     'ID' : ['DOAM4', 'LOAM4', 'COAM2', 'VOAM1']}) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'ID' : ['DOAM4', 'LOAM4', 'COAM2', 'VOAM1']})

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='ID',  sort=False)
```

Есть два датафрейма, нужно сделать что-то типа VLOOKUP функции, только на пайтоне. В результате я хочу получить:

| Names | IDs |
| --- | --- |
| DoammB | DOAM4 |
| LingS | LOAM4 |
| CommI | COAM2 |
| VoammE | VOAM1 |

Проблема в том, что пандас не сохраняет порядок значений и изменяет его на алфавитный. Я думал, что все будет работать когда я добавлю `sort=False`, но никаких изминений не произошло. Может кто-то знает способы получше?

Comment: Пример не работает - в первом датафрейме нет `ID`, мерж ругается. А насчёт сортировки - ну, вообще сортировка не обязана сохраняться при объединении данных. Заведите какое-то поле, где будет прописана нужная сортировка и заново отсортируйте по этому полю датафрейм после объединения.

Comment: @CrazyElf сорри, не заметил, обновил код. Да, наверное самое самым лучшим способом будет создать столбец какой-то и отсортировать.

Comment: С этим рабочим примером вообще-то сортировка остаётся такой же, какой и была в исходном фрейме. Как вы получили ту сортировку, которую показали как желаемый результат - непонятно.

Comment: @CrazyElf это желаемый результат, а не то, что у меня получилось в итоге. Если я, например, попытаюсь сделать то же самое, но уже с 100 IDs и именами, то порядок строк будет сбит

Comment: Ааа, вы хотите, чтобы Id и Name пришли в соответствие, я так вижу вы по совпадению первых букв их объединили? Это же совсем другая задача, при чём тут merge?

Comment: @CrazyElf сорри за плохой пример. Да, чаще всего у IDs и Names совпадают первые 4 буквы, но есть и такие, которые отличатся. У меня есть 2 фрейма, в первом только IDs (не в таком порядке, как в другом фрейме, но так как мне нужно), в другом же фрейме - IDs и Names(их около 1000, они взяты из базы данных). Я хочу брать Names из другого фрейма и сопоставлять их с соответствующими IDs в первом фрейме и при этом оставлять порядок первого фрейма (тот, который меньше)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136521/discussion-between-jack-russtrel-and-crazyelf).

Answer (score 0):

Мой костыльный ответ, который не совсем подходит к таблице автора. Но возможно чем то поможет :)

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'Name': ['LingS', 'DoammB', 'VoammE', 'CommI']}) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'ID': ['DOAM4', 'LOAM4', 'COAM2', 'VOAM1']})

df1.sort_values(by=['Name'], inplace=True)
df2.sort_values(by=['ID'], inplace=True)

df3 = pd.concat([df1['Name'].reset_index(drop=True), 
                df2['ID'].reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)

print(df3)
```

Ответ будет таким:

```
     Name     ID
0   CommI  COAM2
1  DoammB  DOAM4
2   LingS  LOAM4
3  VoammE  VOAM1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df3 = pd.merge(df, df1, on='IDs', how='left')
```